# QMainWindow visibility issue when switching virtual desktop

Tags: python, pyqt, virtual-desktop, mate-desktop

My application has a `QSystemTrayIcon` that toggles the `QMainWindow` visibility when left-clicked.

```
   def tray_icon_activated_cb(reason):
        if reason == QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.main_window.setVisible(not self.main_window.isVisible())
    self.activated.connect(tray_icon_activated_cb)
```

It works correctly, except if I switch virtual desktop while the `QMainWindow` is visible.

For instance:

```
On virtual desktop 1, window hidden
Click
On virtual desktop 1, window visible
Click
On virtual desktop 1, window hidden
Change desktop
On virtual desktop 2, window hidden
Click
On virtual desktop 2, window visible
Click
On virtual desktop 2, window hidden
Change desktop
On virtual desktop 1, window hidden
Click
On virtual desktop 1, window visible
Change desktop
On virtual desktop 2, window hidden
Click
On virtual desktop 2, window hidden  <- wrong
Change desktop
On virtual desktop 1, window hidden
Click
On virtual desktop 1, window hidden  <-- still wrong
```

I only get the QMainWindow back by restarting the application.

I added `print`s in method above and could check that we go through

```
self.main_window.setVisible(not self.main_window.isVisible())
```

because `self.main_window.isVisible()` returns `True` and `False` alternatively.

I just don't know *where* that `QMainWindow` is visible.

Debian Stretch, Mate 1.16.2, Python 3.5.3. I can reproduce with both PyQt4 and PyQt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the window is minimized when hidden then shown from another desktop, but I could not see that because it does not appear in the taskbar, as it has following flags:

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool |
                    QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                    QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

I fixed the issue by unminimizing it explicitly on show event:

```
def showEvent(self, event):
    super().showEvent(event)
    # Ensure the window is not minimized on virtual desktop change
    self.showNormal()
```